# How to get a list of entity with hibernate native query

Tags: hibernate

How can I retrieve a list of a particular entity by using hibernate native query?

I have a Cart table containts two columns: owner_id and item_id

```
cart_id | owner_id | item_id
   1    |    1     |    1
   2    |    1     |    2       
   3    |    2     |    1
   4    |    1     |    1
```

and I want to retrieve a list of item group by a onwer_id:

```
public List<Item> getCustomerCart1(Customer customer) {
    int owner_id = customer.getId();
    LOGGER.info("Retrieve a cart belong to a customer with id {} " + owner_id);
    StringBuffer hql = new StringBuffer();
    hql.append("select {i.*} from item i inner join cart c ");
    hql.append(" on i.item_id = c.item_id and c.owner_id = :owner_id");
    hql.append(" group by c.owner_id");

    Session session = currentSession();

    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(hql.toString());
    query.addEntity(Item.class);
    query.setParameter("owner_id", owner_id);

    List<Item> list = query.list();
    System.out.println("list: " + list.size());
    return list;
}
```

My stacktrace:

```
Hibernate: select {i.*} from item i inner join cart c  on i.item_id = c.item_id and c.owner_id = ? group by c.owner_id
WARN | 2014-09-08 20:42:34,928 | SqlExceptionHelper.java | 144 | SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
ERROR | 2014-09-08 20:42:34,929 | SqlExceptionHelper.java | 146 | ERROR: syntax error at or near "{"
```

I wish to get a list result with size of 2 which containt the infomation of item_id 1 and item_id 2.Can any one help me with the query. Thank you.

Comment: simple use `select i` instead of `select {i.*}`

Answer (score 0):

Use this query (use just `i` instead of `{i.*}`) :

```
select i from item i inner join cart c  on i.item_id = c.item_id and c.owner_id = ? group by c.owner_id
```